# Verify sequence that loops

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm facing a little issue with some coding and I think maths can help me.

Let's say we have two integers min and max

Let's say we have a sequence defined like this :

{min, min+1 ... max-1, max}, {min, min+1 ... max-1, max}, ...

How can we check that two numbers x and y are consecutive ?

I tried to use the modulo operator to manage the loop without success (The min boundary makes it wrong)

Is there a relation between x and y that is always true in this sequence ?
I tried to do it without conditionnals. The problem seems pretty simple but since I can't find a way I ask this community.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two numbers are consequtive if $|x-y|=1$ or if $\{x,y\}=\{\mathrm{min},\mathrm{max}\}$.

If we assume that $x<y$, then that simplifies. Then they are consequtive if $x+1=y$ or if $x=\min$ and $y=\max$.

I don't see a simpler way of checking this. You must check two different conditions, as both of them might hold.

Comment: Thanks 5xum. I finally given up on trying to solve this without "ifs". I thought it would be possible but since I couldn't and you seem to say the same here i stopped killing my mind. Thanks for your time !